# Is it possible to use List<?> from item proccesor in ItemWriter instead of Chunk<? extends List<T> in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In my spring boot + batch application i use next approach.
In `ItemReader<UUID>` i read `batch_table`, in `ItemProcessor<List<Payment>>` i select related payments and in `ItemWriter` i would like to accept this `List<Payment>` as an argument instead of `Chunk<? extends List<Payement>`.
Is there any better approach?

Actually i might achieve similar if i specify `chunkSize = 1`, and just rely on that in `ItemWriter`, but it seems like workaround.

Comment: If your item processor returning, item writer needs to accept ‵Chunk<? extends List<Payement‵ . Chunk class implements Itertable so we can use for each loop . getItems method might from Chunk is another way. https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/Chunk.html#getItems()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use List<?> from item processor in ItemWriter instead of Chunk<? extends List> in Spring Batch. In chunk based batch processing, reader and processor reads/processes single record at a time, keeps it in buffer and sends all records to writer after chunk size has met. If you notice signature of ItemWriter, it is List<? extends T> items, which means it accepts list of items returned by processor.

You can implement your own ItemWriter that accepts List<?> as an argument instead of Chunk<? extends List>. Here is an example:

```
public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<List<?>> {
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends List<?>> items) throws Exception {
        for (List<?> item : items) {
            // process item
        }
}
```

}

Comment: hi Tahir. So question is about how to avoid List<List?> in item writer. I would like to process single List returned from processor as single chunk in single transaction

Comment: @RomanOborin I think you are looking for delegate pattern in your item writer. One itemwriter calls another. Please take a look at example in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/iosample/internal/MultiLineTradeItemWriter.java